# Python One Hot Encoder: 'PandasArray' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have the following program:

```
cat_feats = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b',
                'c', 'd', 'e']

onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
# convert each categorical feature from integer
# to one-hot
for feature in cat_feats:
    data[feature] = data[feature].array.reshape(len(data[feature]), 1)
    data[feature] = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(data[feature])
```

I am having issues with this. I get:

```
'PandasArray' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

The output of data.head() before using the encoder is this:

```
 0          2          1               4           6             3     2       1              37
 2          1          7               2          10             0     4       1              37
 3          2         15               2           6             0     2       1              37
 5          2          0               4           7             1     4       1              37
 7          4         14               2           9             0     4       1              37
```

This output is of type DataFrame and contains only integers which I am trying to convert to one-hot. I have tried .array, .values, .array.reshape(-1, 1), but none of these things are working. I found that trying .values seemed to work in the first line of the for loop, but I got garbage from my one-hot conversion.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These following informations might be helpful:

1. The type of some of the objects:

   - `data[feature]`: `pandas.Series`
   - `data[feature].values`: `numpy.ndarray`
2. You can `reshape` a `numpy.ndarray` but not a pandas.Series, so you need to use `.values` to get a `numpy.ndarray`
3. When you assign a `numpy.ndarray` to `data[feature]`, automatic type conversion occurs, so `data[feature] = data[feature].values.reshape(-1, 1)` doesn't seem to do anything.
4. `fit_transform` takes an array-like(Need to be a 2D array, e.g. `pandas.DataFrame` or `numpy.ndarray`) object as argument because `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` is designed to fit/transform multiple features at the same time, input `pandas.Series`(1D array) will cause error.
5. `fit_transform` will return sparse matrix(or 2-d array), assign it to a `pandas.Series` may cause a disaster.

(**Not Recommended**) If you insist on processing one feature after another:

```py
for feature in categorical_feats:
    encoder = OneHotEncoder()
    tmp_ohe_data = pd.DataFrame(
        encoder.fit_transform(data[feature].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray(),
        columns=encoder.get_feature_names(),
    )
    data = pd.concat([tmp_ohe_data, data], axis=1).drop([feature], axis=1)
```

I **Recommended** do encoding like this:

```py
encoder = OneHotEncoder()

ohe_data = pd.DataFrame(
    encoder.fit_transform(data[categorical_feats]).toarray(),
    columns=encoder.get_feature_names(),
)
res = pd.concat([ohe_data, data], axis=1).drop(categorical_feats, axis=1)
```

`pandas.get_dummies` is also a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for your great response! Just a quick question, why do you use .toarray() and not .values? Doesn't .values also turn the data into a numpy array? I don't know how I would prefer one over the other.

Comment: `fit_transform` will return a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html), which has no method:`values`, so we need to use [`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html) to get a dense ndarray.